# Why is Consul not performing health checks?

Tags: java, spring-boot, consul

In my Spring Boot application, I register my service like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class FrontendBootstrapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FrontendBootstrapper.class, args);
    }
}
```

When calling the `/health` endpoint in a browser, I get the following result:

```
{"description":"Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client","status":"UP"}
```

which is what I expected. However, Consul never calls this endpoint, even though I set the health check interval to 10s. Here is my `application.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=frontend
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.healthCheckInterval=10s
```

However, the service is always marked as critical in the Consul UI.

I am running Consul from the official Docker container. Also, what is the appropriate Spring property to set `DeregisterCriticalAfter`?

**Edit:**

This seems to be an issue with the Docker image only, when I run Consul by calling `consul agent -dev`, everything works as expected. Did anyone get this to work with the Docker image?